# Confirmation with Data when Deleting a row in GridView is triggered only when data is number or null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I want to confirm the deletion of a row displaying a field value along with a message but this works only when the field contains numbers or null. The event is not triggered otherwise.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"  OnClientClick='<%# "return ConfirmDel(" + Eval("Fname") + ");" %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fname" HeaderText="Fname" SortExpression="Fname" />
        . . . .
</asp:GridView>
```

and here is the javascript

```
 function ConfirmDel(fname) {
        return confirm('Are you sure to delete ' + fname);
 }
```

I searched a while for a similar question but found not the exact one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really looks fine. The only think I could think of is that the event doesn't fire when  Eval("Fname") evaluates to Null.

I would try

```
OnClientClick='<%# "return xx(" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Fname").ToString()) ? 
                                  "debug - is this firing" : Eval("Fname") + ");" %>'
```

Obviously remove the debug message one you have it working

Your xx function is incorrect as well - I'm assuming this is just a cut and paste error

```
function xx(fname) {         
    return confirm('Are you sure to delete ' + fname); 
}
```

Note ending `}`

Lastly - I really would change the name of `xx` to something more descriptive. I'm sure this is just debug/demo code so apologies for pointing it our. Just to flag up for other readers really.

**EDIT**

I think this is it

```
 OnClientClick="return xx('<%# Eval('Fname') %>');"
```

Note the two additional `'`. You need to pass this through as a string otherwise you will get strange effects depending what goes in. I would still guard against nulls as before though

Also the Eval is in the wrong place - you are evaluating the entire javascript string but you just should do the datafield.

**EDIT 2**

I'm trying the above and it just isn't working. If I were you I would abandon the notion of using eval to build the `OnClientClick` in the markup. Do it in the code behind in the `RowDataBound` event - using the `FindControl` method to pick out the link. That definitely works (honest)

I think this is my last word to be honest. Good luck

Almost the last word - just for completeness here's what I would do

```
void detailsGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         string foreName = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Fname").ToString();
         LinkButton lnkButton = e.Row.FindControl("lnkLinkID") as LinkButton;
         lnkButton.OnClientClick = "Delete message to " + foreName
    } 
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for the correction. Embedding single quote produces Server tag not well formed error. The use of the ternary operator has no difference. In both cases it produces string, but that is the problem, the event is fired only when the passed value is null or number. I'm wondering to know how javascript handles parameters

Comment: @nuux i see why the server tag error happened. I'm convinced you need quotes when you call the function. I've amended it to escape the quotes - is that any better? Now you've got double quotes for the OnClientClick function and single quotes for the js function param

Comment: still the error Server tag is thrown. I also think that why js don't fire could be the absence of those single quotes.

Comment: @nuux - OK I'm embarrassed - should have spotted it before. This is it - the evals in the wrong place. see correction

Comment: The last tuned one works great! Thank you again ! Also I found it on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewConfirmDelete.aspx)